# How to (C#) : Dynamically Create multiple controls on add click and access their properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to add Text box control on each click event of Add button.
How do I implement event handler for each controls created
dynamically at runtime and then Access their properties from Event
Handler.

**C#**

```
static int counter = 0;              
        protected void addMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            for (int j = 1; j <= counter; j++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                Button btn = new Button();
                tb.ID = "Tb" + counter;
                // tb.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
                btn.ID = "btn" + counter;
                btn.Text = "Remove";
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
```

But not able to access Text property of newly added textboxes. 
*Would really appreciate if someone could help me..*

Comment: Show us what do you have so far.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: I've used `<asp:placeholder id="ph"/>`  & then trying to add controls

Comment: Edit and post your code in original question. Also please choose tags carefully. I initially did not understand whether you want to do this in JavaScript or C#.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the browser on the server? What "Event Handler" are you referring to?

Comment: I have deleted my answer. I think you edited question content with code and now it looks like you want to do something else than I interpreted initially. Do you mean you cannot set Text property of tb which you are currently adding OR of those textboxes which were added previously?

Comment: @vnikhil    I just wanted to access text entered by user in textbox `tb`, how'll I get that from `tb`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

**For adding text box dynamicaly**

```
protected void AddTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.CreateTextBox("txtDynamic" + index);
}

private void CreateTextBox(string id)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = id;
    pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(txt);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<br />";
    pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(lt);
}


protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("txtDynamic")).ToList();
    int i = 1;
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        this.CreateTextBox("txtDynamic" + i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Getting values of dynamically created TextBoxes**

```
protected void GetTextBoxValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    foreach (TextBox textBox in pnlTextBoxes.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        message += textBox.ID + ": " + textBox.Text + "\\n";
    }
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

**ASP Code**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTextBoxes" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<hr />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="AddTextBox" />
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get Values" OnClick="GetTextBoxValues" />
```